# Jquery to get parent div image source

Tags: javascript, jquery

My Html goes like this,

```
<div>
    <div>
        <input id="20171" name="StyleID" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="StyleID" type="hidden" value="false">
    </div>
    <div class="imgContainer" style="padding-left: 3px; font-size: 18px; float:left;">
        <img src="http://localhost:61137/Images/8501.jpg" width="150px" height="150px">
    </div>
    <div>
        <span id="1002" class="ImagePlating"></span>
        <span id="1003" class="ImagePlating"></span>
        <span id="1004" class="ImagePlating"></span>
        <span id="1005" class="ImagePlating"></span>
    </div>    
</div>

...

<div >
    <div >
        <input id="20162" name="StyleID" type="checkbox" value="true">
        <input name="StyleID" type="hidden" value="false">
    </div>
    <div class="imgContainer" style="padding-left: 3px; font-size: 18px; float:left;">
        <img src="http://localhost:61137/Images/8498.jpg" width="150px" height="150px">
    </div>
    <div style="padding-left: 3px; font-size: 18px; float:left;">
        <span id="1002" class="ImagePlating"></span>
        <span id="1003" class="ImagePlating"></span>
        <span id="1004" class="ImagePlating"></span>
        <span id="1005" class="ImagePlating"></span>
        <span id="1006" class="ImagePlating"></span>
        <span id="1007" class="ImagePlating"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

On click of the span I am trying to change the source for the div with class "imgContainer", also trying to get the Id of the parent div's checkbox with the following Jquery.

```
$(".ImagePlating").on("click", function (e) {
  $(this).parent()
         .sibilings()
         .find('.imgContainer')
         .child()
         .attr("src", "http://localhost:61137/Images/Img-Loading.gif");
  var id = $(this).parent()
                  .find('input[type='checkbox']')
                  .attr('id');
});
```

However I am not sure how can I achieve that using JQuery, the above Jquery which I tried looks wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try below code : Use `parent()` to get parent div and then use `prev()` to find previous element with `class="imgContainer"` and change `src`.  Use same `$imageContainer` and prev() to find checkbox.

Also use double quotes for `type="checkbox"`

```
$(".ImagePlating").on("click", function (e) {
  var $imageContainer = $(this).parent().prev('.imgContainer');
  $imageContainer.find('img').attr("src", "http://localhost:61137/Images/Img-Loading.gif");
  var id = $imageContainer.prev().find('input[type="checkbox"]').attr('id');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use like this

```
$(".ImagePlating").click(function () {
     $(this).parent().prev().find("img").attr("src", "new src");

});
```

`.prev()` will select the element just above it. Then using `find()` you can find the children.

Comment: Thanks though Bhushan helped to find id too.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
$(".ImagePlating").on("click", function (e) {
  $(this).parent()
         .prev('.imgContainer') //Image container is not a sibling
         .find('img')
         .attr("src", "http://localhost:61137/Images/Img-Loading.gif");
  var id = $(this).parent()
                  .find('input[type='checkbox']')
                  .attr('id');
});
```